# Error: application file does not exist

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have installed a new zf project, and get the next error:

> Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\zend\public\index.php on line 18

I have set the include path and in addition i have uploaded zf to the library folder.

But, I can't find any trace to a file named `Application.php` ...

Comment: ZF2. jeffrey, obviously that's what the problem says. I have no such file in my zend library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere along the line you have mixed ZF1 and ZF2 instructions or code. There is no `Zend/Application.php` in ZF2 (this is a ZF1 thing), and ZF2 apps do not generally have a 'library' folder. So either you are using ZF2 but have followed some app setup instructions for ZF1, or you've used the ZF1 command line tool to create a ZF1 project and have then put ZF2 into the library folder.

Here is the ZF2 skeleton app: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication - this should give you an idea what your app should look like.

Answer (score 1):

As the error obviously says `Zend/Application.php` is not there. Check you include path and your folder.

Comment: obviously that's what the problem says. I have no such file in my zend library.